# C# MySql Syntax Exception when querying against an IP addres

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, select

I'm querying against an IP address stored in a table of a database with the following:

```
"SELECT user_id, is_login FROM users WHERE last_ip_address = '" + this.GetIPAddress() + "'"
```

I know that the IP is in the table because I see it there. I'm literally staring at it, but this query returns no rows.

When I run it without the single tick quotes ('), I get a syntax error:

```
"SELECT user_id, is_login FROM users WHERE last_ip_address = " + this.GetIPAddress()
```

So where is this going wrong? The IP returned by the function is the standard format ###.###.###.### IP address, and the syntax error itself is this:

```
{"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.##.#' at line 1"}
```

Edit: Some more info, the field itself is a varchar(30) type, and it says Collation = latin1_swedish_ci, but I don't even know what that is.

Thanks

Comment: What type of object does `GetIPAddress()` return?  If it's an `IPAddress` type, you need to call `ToString()` to convert it to an actual string for use in your SQL.

Comment: Returns a string. Thanks though.

Comment: why do you concatenate your query? Use `SqlCommand.Parameters` where you'll be able to add parameter by value and/or by SqlDbType. 
This will cache query and will avoid sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `LIKE` then:

```
"SELECT user_id, is_login FROM users WHERE last_ip_address LIKE '%" + this.GetIPAddress() + "%'"
```

**Edit**: I would try to change that collation to *UTF8*.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am sorry for the confusion. I am very new to using MySql with C# and very VERY new (like I mean I just started today) with MySqlConnector.

To make a long answer short, I was trying to treat the table like, well, a table, and just read from it like a two dimensional array, when what I needed to be doing was using the MySqlDataReader. I found a good answer here:

[How to read columns and rows with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235552/how-to-read-columns-and-rows-with-c)

Thanks all for your help and advice.